# Why am I redirected directly to login page instead of index.html in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning to design a login page in Spring Boot. I have not created any file named login, instead I have created an index page but by default it is redirecting me to login page?

```
package com.main.medipp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
     
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (UserDetailsService) new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
         
        return authProvider;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sign_up").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
                  
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

This is the code  , i used , please help me with what changes should i make now!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have secured your `/` endpoint, you will get redirected to the default login page. To fix that, add a rule to the `/` endpoint to disable authentication and redirect to the index page via a **Controller**.

Comment: PLease check, i have updated the code in question, what changes should i need to make .

Comment: please check this code